# Find active tab name in an Excel VSTO addin

Tags: c++, vsto, office-addins

How can I get the active Ribbon tab name within an addin, or alternatively enumerate the displayed tabs' names? (tab name can be "home", "insert", "View" etc.)
for example in the below screenshot the active tab is "insert".

[image: selected tab]